# Why int(string) gives value error

Tags: python, typeerror

I was just wondering why when I take an integer of a string like int('string') why you recieve a value error in python 3.2 and not a type error. I see the definition of a type error is defined on the python site as the follows: Raised when an operation or function is applied to an object of inappropriate type. The associated value is a string giving details about the type mismatch.

isn't int the operator and the string is the inappropriate type? When I do this I receive a ValueError and do not understand the reason for this.

Here is the code
So when i instantiate the class with a rank that has a string to try and purposely get an error I receive a valueerror and not a type as I would expect.

```
class Card:

#attributes
list_rank=   ["","Ace","2","3","4","5","6","7","8","9","10","Jack","Queen","King"]
list_suit={"d":"diamonds","c":"clubs","h":"hearts","s":"spades"}

#initialize rank and suit
def __init__(self,rank,suit):



self.rank=int(rank)

self.suit=suit




#return the rank of the card
def getRank(self):
    return(self.list_rank[self.rank])

#return the suit of the card
def getSuit(self):
    return(self.list_suit[self.suit])



#value of the cards
def bjValue(self):
    if(self.rank<10):
        return(self.rank)
    else:
        return(10)


#return the rank and suit of the card
def __str__(self):

    return (self.list_rank[self.rank]+" of "+self.list_suit[self.suit])
```

Comment: every character has an integer called the ASCII , are you aware of it?

Comment: For what it's worth, Python 2.x raises a `ValueError` as well.

Comment: Are you actually _applying_ this function to anything?

Comment: `int` is not an operator, it's a built-in class. And when you invoke `int(x)` you are calling the constructor of that class.

Comment: For the record, getting a `TypeError` won't help you if you're trying to do `int("Ace")`

Comment: Didn't know each character has an integer called ASCII. Thanks.

Comment: Note that `'string'` is a valid number in base 36, i.e. `int('string', base=36)` evaluates to `1743045676` (decimal). ;-)

Comment: @FrerichRaabe thanks for adding to the general confusion :D

Comment: Thank you everyone for you help.

Answer (score 7):

To understand the difference you must understand the difference between type and value. The type of "abc" is string, which you can check by running

```
type("abc")  # -> string
```

The value of the literal `"abc"` is simply the value itself. If you had an expression like `"ab" + "c"` the value would also be `"abc"`.

That's why you get the `ValueError` and not a `TypeError`; `int` *expects* a `string`, which you gave it - so it's the correct type - but the `value` has to be something that can be interpreted as an integer and `"abc"` is not an integer obviously.

To try this out, see the difference between:

```
int('abc')
# throws:
# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'abc'
```

and

```
int(None)
# throws:
# TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'NoneType'
```

The fact that `"abc"` doesn't immediately look like an integer doesn't stop us from interpreting it as one, however. In a different [base](http://betterexplained.com/articles/numbers-and-bases/) it could still be interpreted as a number.

For example: binary numbers, as you probably know, only use `0`s and `1`s, and hexadecimal numbers are usually represented using the digits `0` - `9` and the letters `a` - `f`. The [`int`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/functions.html#int) function takes an optional argument that tells it which base to use, so if we try interpreting `"abc"` again but as a hexadecimal number, we get:

```
int('abc',  base=16)
# returns 2748
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch. That makes much more sense now. I wasn't really thinking I guess. Thanks again.

Answer (score 3):

because `int()` accepts a string as a parameter for example `int('1')` will ouptut `1`. so `'1'` is an appropriat value but `'a'` is not

Comment: @user3630439 The point is that passing a string to the `int` constructor is not a type error - many strings are valid (e.g. `"12345"`). So raising a type error for a string does not make sense (but raising a type error for e.g. `None` is perfectly plausible, as André Laszlo demonstrates).

Comment: because `'a'` as I said is a wrong value since it is not an integer but `'1'` is an accepted value. keep in mind that both has the same type

Answer (score 2):

TL;DR: You get a `ValueError` if the data you supply is the correct **type** for the function that you are trying to use but the **value** makes no sense.
You get a `TypeError` if the function you are trying to use doesn't understand what to do with the **type** of data you are supplying.

Examples:

For example:

```
int('123') 
>>>>123

int('somestring')
>>>>Traceback (most recent call last):
    File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
    ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'somestring'
```

so it is trying to convert the string to an int using base 10, where only the characters 0-9 make any sense. Basically Python is saying "I was expecting a string, but I don't understand that string"

Compare that to this:

```
>>>>int('FF', base=16)  #hexadecimal
255

>>>>int('9', base=8) # can only use 0-7 in octal
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'somestring'


>>>>int('somestring', base=36)
2913141654103084L
```

(Base 36 uses 0-9 then a-z as valid numerical characters)

If you try using the wrong type completely, such as `int( {'apple':1} )` then you get a `TypeError` and a helpful message telling you why it hasn't worked:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<interactive input>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: int() argument must be a string or a number, not 'dict'
```